# svg href broken image wordpress elementor

Tags: wordpress, svg, href, elementor

I have a svg file with href link inside polygon. I am putting it in elementor, but no matter what way I am putting it in. Whenever I hit on the link, it will just show a broken image. But if I am not using elementor , things go well. Any idea on preventing this. Thanks.

Comment: Actually I add this and it works <object type="image/svg+xml" data="xxx.svg">
    <img src="xxx.svg" />
</object>